How to know what sample size (number of cells) is sufficient to determine what percentage of cells are above a threshold?
I have a samples with different cell types (one cell type is shown above). I have calculated for each sample and cell type a threshold signifying non proliferating vs proliferating cells. Cells above this threshold are proliferating and cells below this threshold are not. The question I have is, how do I know or have confidence in the sample size or total cells I am using is correct? In other words, whats the minimum number of cells I need to carry out the percent above threshold calculation and how would I go about figuring that out? I ask this because in the image below the total cells are in the thousands but I have some cell types that have total cells in the 100s or sometimes even less. Appreciate any help.

To validate the threshold for cell proliferation you have a tough road ahead.  You need to show that if a cell count is below the threshold it doesn’t matter biologically how far below the threshold the cell count lies, and if it’s above the threshold, how far above is likewise irrelevant.  It is very rare for being above a threshold to be biologically relevant.  You’d have to show that an all-or-nothing process is in play at the threshold, i.e., going past the threshold is like falling off a cliff.
In the vast majority of cases using absolute or relative cell counts is the biologically relevant thing to do.  And it certainly boosts your effective sample size.  Details may be found here.

Hi Frank, I appreciate your help. I do not completely understand so may I ask if you could elaborate? Sorry for the confusion. Also, would I be able to do something similar to sample size calculation (https://select-statistics.co.uk/calculators/sample-size-calculator-population-proportion/)  to see how many total cells i need to have to carry out the percent above threshold calculation.  Then, any sample/cell_type below that threshold I can get rid of and not carry out the analysis.

I was addressing with you might avoid the threshold altogether.  Proliferation is on a continuum.

Oh ok, that makes sense.
